# ACF page while loop breaks footer while loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, while-loop, advanced-custom-fields

So basically i have a main page and a footer page. Both are seperate .php files.

Im using [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/flexible-content/) for this site.

Following the documentation, ive created a while loop for my 'flexible content' in the main page and it works, displaying all the data that gets looped and hooked from the CMS input fields.

My Problem is in the footer, i have a while loop that displays links, but it wont display **unless** i remove the while loop from the main page, then the links display in the footer.

I honnestly dot get why this happens ive tested allot and get my head wrapped around this, please help.

**Main page code:**

```
<?php

// check if the flexible content field has rows of data
if( have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows('flexible_content_field_name') ) : the_row();

        // check current row layout
        if( get_row_layout() == 'gallery' ):

            // check if the nested repeater field has rows of data
            if( have_rows('images') ):

                echo '<ul>';

                // loop through the rows of data
                while ( have_rows('images') ) : the_row();

                    $image = get_sub_field('image');

                    echo '<li><img src="' . $image['url'] . '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" /></li>';

                endwhile;

                echo '</ul>';

            endif;

        endif;

    endwhile;

else :

    // no layouts found

endif;

?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

**Footer Code:**

```
<div class="links">

         <?php

            if( have_rows('footer_page_links', 'option') ): 
            var_dump("test");
            while( have_rows('footer_page_links', 'option') ): the_row();

            ?>

            <p><a href="<?php the_sub_field('footer_link');   ?>"><?php the_sub_field('footer_link_name'); ?></a></p>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>   


</div>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

I would just like to add , not even the `vardump()` displays in the footer if main page while loop is implemented so it never gets inside the footer loop. The footer uses ACF option page - > [LINK](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-from-an-options-page/)

Also all other option fields in footer displays, if its not within the while loop. I have removed the main page while loop then the footer while loop works, and this only happens with flexible content, my other pages with loops, that does non consists of flexible content works perfectly.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the ACF Options page, but here's my guess. Above your code, at some point you start the page loop (something like: <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>)
If you don't have it, add it, and then close it before the footer. If you do have it, just close it before the footer.

Comment: hi @VictoriaRuiz, thanks,you talking about my main page? i do have it and also i close the brackets before calling the footer. Just did not want to add code that i know at this point has nothing to do with why it breaks. I removed part for part and eventually realized the above code is the only reason it breaks. So in main page if its just the `if (have_posts()) { while (have_posts()) { the_post();` with some content the footer links wil display, but adding flexible content within this `if`breaks footer links.

Comment: You need to close this if/while before you reach the footer. If that doesn't work, there's always wp_reset_query: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_query/

Comment: Thanks for trying to help @VictoriaRuiz, so o tried `wp_reset_query();` not working.. you would suggest adding that after the main page flexible content loop right?

Comment: Yes, after the loop is closed.

Comment: You will need to echo 'the_sub_field', for example <?php echo the_sub_field('footer_link_name'); ?>.

Comment: the `wp_reset_query();` is just not working, also the `echo` does not work, like i said in question everything is fine on other pages, but the flexible content breaks my footer, if i remove the flexible content `loop` it works perfectly fine.

Comment: @VictoriaRuiz problem solved, took me only a week lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So This issue is resolved on my side, after contacting the ACF guys, they made a duplicate of what i did and could not recreate my issue.

Which got me thinking since i had the latest Wordpress (Version 4.9.7) the only difference is the hosting.

What i used on localhost was XAMP Version 3.2.2, which i did not think was the problem, but **it was**, so upgraded to a live server and everything works as expected, so for future ref should you run into these simple unexplained code errors, check the hosting, or upgrade.